# How to open a form only if its book is active

Tags: forms, vba, excel

I have a shotcut to show a form

```
Form1.Show //shortcut is ctrl+Q
```

If I activate another workbook and press ctrl+Q - the form also appears
I want it appearing only if its book is Active.
I tried:

```
If ThisWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook Then Form1.Show
```

or

```
If ActiveWorkbook = ThisWorkbook Then Form1.Show
```

And got syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about referring to the .name?

```
If ThisWorkbook.Name = ActiveWorkbook.Name Then
   MsgBox "Is Active"
End If
```

Even Excel 2013 will not open two workbooks with the same name at the same time.

Comment: I just tested, you should not be assigning, you should be comparing. I will add in the `if` to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveWorkbook and Thisworkbook are objects; therefore to compare them you have to use `is` instead of `=`.

```
If Thisworkbook is ActhiveWorkbook then Form1.Show
```